# How to Print PDF in IOS7

Tags: ios, pdf, printing

In my application i have `PDF` file url i want to take printout form the device please tell me how to achieve this one. I have the `PDF` url in my loadview i want to print just by clicking the `UIButton`.

MY Load view code.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
      NSURL *myURL =[NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"];
     NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
     [webview loadRequest:myRequest];

  }
```

Please tell me how to achieve this one i have been stuck here for long time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below function

```
- (IBAction)printWebPage:(id)sender
    {


        UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
        if(!controller)
        {
            return;
        }

        UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
        ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            if(!completed && error){

            }
        };


        // Obtain a printInfo so that we can set our printing defaults.
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        // This application produces General content that contains color.
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        // We'll use the URL as the job name
        printInfo.jobName = @"";
        // Set duplex so that it is available if the printer supports it. We
        // are performing portrait printing so we want to duplex along the long edge.
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        // Use this printInfo for this print job.
        controller.printInfo = printInfo;

        // Be sure the page range controls are present for documents of > 1 page.
        controller.showsPageRange = YES;

        // This code uses a custom UIPrintPageRenderer so that it can draw a header and footer.
        MyPrintPageRenderer *myRenderer = [[MyPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
        // The MyPrintPageRenderer class provides a jobtitle that it will label each page with.
        myRenderer.jobTitle = printInfo.jobName;
        // To draw the content of each page, a UIViewPrintFormatter is used.
        UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [sclviwReport viewPrintFormatter];

    #if SIMPLE_LAYOUT
        /*
         For the simple layout we simply set the header and footer height to the height of the
         text box containing the text content, plus some padding.

         To do a layout that takes into account the paper size, we need to do that
         at a point where we know that size. The numberOfPages method of the UIPrintPageRenderer
         gets the paper size and can perform any calculations related to deciding header and
         footer size based on the paper size. We'll do that when we aren't doing the simple
         layout.
         */
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:HEADER_FOOTER_TEXT_HEIGHT];
        CGSize titleSize = [myRenderer.jobTitle sizeWithFont:font];
        myRenderer.headerHeight = myRenderer.footerHeight = titleSize.height + HEADER_FOOTER_MARGIN_PADDING;
    #endif
        [myRenderer addPrintFormatter:viewFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
        // Set our custom renderer as the printPageRenderer for the print job.
        controller.printPageRenderer = myRenderer;
        [myRenderer release];

        // The method we use presenting the printing UI depends on the type of
        // UI idiom that is currently executing. Once we invoke one of these methods
        // to present the printing UI, our application's direct involvement in printing
        // is complete. Our custom printPageRenderer will have its methods invoked at the
        // appropriate time by UIKit.

        //    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        //        [controller presentFromBarButtonItem:printButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPad
        //    else
        //        [controller presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];  // iPhone
        [controller presentFromRect:CGRectMake(btnReportPrint.frame.origin.x, btnReportPrint.frame.origin.y+40, btnReportPrint.frame.size.width, btnReportPrint.frame.size.height) inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

    }
```

This will open the pop over controller with the printer name. Choose one of the printer from list to print the web page. Instead of `sclviwReport` use your `webview`

Comment: I'm getting two errors now one is property jobtitle not found on object of type UIprintpagerenderer

Comment: another errror is undeclared identifier btnreportprint

Comment: Instead of btnreportprint use other button from where u want to show popover for print.

Comment: do i have to use two button of this the in popover button wt ihave to do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51731/discussion-between-user3427551-and-svrushal)

Comment: u told i have to give popover button thats i asked do i have to create a another button called popover inside that popover button which method i have to invoke